# Interrupting MessageChannelPartitionHandler

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using a JmsOutboundGateway with a MessageChannelPartitionHandler for a partitioned batch job. I would like to be able to interrupt this code in the handle method

```
Message<Collection<StepExecution>> message = messagingGateway.receive(replyChannel);
```

From another thread I tried to call interrupt() on this thread. What is the best way to add this functionality?

CLARIFICATION:

The interruption does work. However, the thread for each partition that did receive a response has a stack trace(below). These threads remain blocked which pulls them from that threadpool and they are unavailable for subsequent partitioned jobs.

```
            <b>Thread: springbatch.partitioned.jms.taskExecutor-1</b> :
        priority:5, demon:false, threadId:823, threadState:TIMED_WAITING<br />
        <blockquote>
            - waiting on <0xf483c36> (a
            java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)<br />sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native
            Method)<br />java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)<br />
            java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)<br />
            java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.obtainReplyFromContainer(JmsOutboundGateway.java:865)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.doSendAndReceiveAsync(JmsOutboundGateway.java:809)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.sendAndReceiveWithContainer(JmsOutboundGateway.java:649)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JmsOutboundGateway.java:580)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:52)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$1.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)<br />
            org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)<br />
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)<br />java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)<br />java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)<br />
            <br />
```

How can I access these threads to interrupt also?

Answer (score 0):

Interrupting the thread will work; however, the interrupt is caught (and the interrupt bit re-set in the `QueueChannel`).

After this, the received message is null so the partition handler will throw a `MessageTimeoutException` instead.

There is currently no way to determine whether the timeout is because of a real timeout or the interrupt.